# Query Appsync graphql with 3 different combinations

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am using appsync with amplify and trying to figure out how to query based on two different selectors.  Basically I need to either query all if neither `county or facility` are supplied, query with `county` while `facility` is empty, or query with `facility` while `county` is empty.  I thought I could wrap this into 1 query but it doesn't seem like I can.  My appsync schemas look like this.

```
type Client 
  @model
  @key(name: "clientByCountyOrFacility", fields: ["county", "facility"], queryField: "getClientsByCountyOrFacility") 
  @searchable {
  id: ID!
  facility: String!
  county: String!
  products: [Product] @connection(name: "ClientProducts")
}

type Product 
  @model 
  @searchable {
  id: ID!
  client: Client @connection(name: "ClientProducts")
}
```

I can get this to work by using (below query) but I am worried this will run into the 100 scan limit because it uses the `listClients` query underneath.  Possibly if there was an easy way to change that could be a solution but it seems the files in amplify are autogenerated.

```
query getClientsByCountyOrFacility($county: String = "", $facility: String = "") {
    listClients(filter: {
    county: {
      contains: $county
    }
    facility: {
      contains: $facility
    }
  }) {
    items {
      id
      products {
        items {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I added the `@key` to see if I could create an index but it doesn't like that and I'm at a lose for how to acquire the data.  How do I go about building this schema and query to get the data back?